# How do I know I've write enough test cases?

Tags: testing

Given a example:

```
int sum(int* ary, int n);
```

I've written some test case for it

```
TEST("sum case 1")
{
    int a1[] = {1,2,3,4};
    ASSERT(sum(a1, 4) == 10);
}

TEST("sum case 2 negative")
{
   int a2[] = {-1,-2,-3};
   ASSERT(sum(a2, 3) == -6);
}

TEST("sum case 3 0 number")
{
  ASSERT(sum(NULL, 0) == 0);
}

TEST("sum case 4 big number")
{
   int a4[] = {1243142325,23423525,23525245,124313}
  ASSERT(sum(a4) == .... );
}

TEST("sum case 5 mix")
{
   int a5[] = {1243142325, -1, 0,  -2224313}
   ASSERT(sum(a5) == .... );
}
```

Sometimes when I write a function, I worry about I will miss some possible cases. Then I stop and try hard to think other possible cases like negative integer, null, very big number, and other strange input.

It costs my time and make me think is it necessary to write so many cases for one function? How many cases should I write are enough to make test reliable? Or should I just write the normal case first, then write another cases later if I have free time?

Answer (score 0):

You could focus on two types of testing - **White Box** and **Black Box** testing.

For **Black Box** testing you will want to do what you already described, find extrema and border cases. This includes [border-valua analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary-value_analysis) and [error guessing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_guessing)

For **White Box** testing you assume that the code of the tested functionality is known. You will want to cover as many lines or "branches" of that code. There are several metrics which you could follow and even use tools to support analysis of your [coverage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage).

If you start to test higher levels of your code (i.e., not just unit tests) you will focus more on **user stories** and **features**. Here you reproduce the described user actions and assert that these are possible and produce the expected results/outputs.